# Get value in an excel form control with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, forms

I need to read the information that is in a cell that is actually a form control. As shown in the figure.

[image]

When showing the DataFrame, we can see that the information that is in control (equip_003) does not appear in the pandas DataFrame.

[image: DataFrame in Jupyter Labs]

```
import pandas as pd

arquivo = 'exemplo.xlsx'
dict_planilhas = pd.read_excel(arquivo, sheet_name=None, header=None)

dados = dict_planilhas['Dados']
```

Is there a way to get the value that is inside an Excel spreadsheet form control, using Python?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
dict_planilhas = pd.read_csv(arquivo, names=['Dados'], header=None)
```

Or:

```
dict_planilhas = pd.read_csv(arquivo)
```